# Opening second frame clears all objects held by ArrayLists in first frame

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jframe

so I'm trying to program an RPG board game or at least a part of it.

I have two frames, one is the main frame where the game happens. The second frame is meant for character creation.

I am initializing the second frame with a button inside the first frame. In the newly opened frame the player can set his/her values and create the character.

The problem that's ocurring to me is that as soon as I hit the line

```
cw = new CreationWindow();
```

the ArrayList playerlist which contains the Character-Objects seems to get cleared. I tested this inside the debug mode and a breakpoint right before and after this line showed that this is where the ArrayList loses its held Objects.

I don't really understand what is happening there and I would be glad if someone could explain this to me!

Classes used:

MainWindow

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

private CreationWindow cw;

private JPanel contentPane;

// Startscreen
private ArrayList<JButton> startscreenCreateList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
private ArrayList<JLabel[]> playerValuelist = new ArrayList<JLabel[]>();

// Objects
private ArrayList<Character> playerlist = new ArrayList<Character>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public MainWindow() {
    setTitle("Legends of Andor");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 550, 460);
    setResizable(false);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    // Startscreen
    setStartscreen();

}

private void setStartscreen() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        startscreenCreateList.add(new JButton("Add"));
        startscreenCreateList.get(x).setBounds(40, 45 + x * 95, 100, 30);
        startscreenCreateList.get(x).addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                /*
                 * 1. the initialization of the CreationWindow Object seems to set every ArrayList of MainWindow "null"
                 * "null"
                 */
                cw = new CreationWindow();
                cw.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(startscreenCreateList.get(x));

        // Start-Button
        JButton start = new JButton("Start!");
        start.setBounds(410, 370, 100, 30);
        contentPane.add(start);
    }

}

// Methods
public void createCharacter(Character c) {
    /*
     * 5. adds Character Object received from CreationWindow to ArrayList
     */
    playerlist.add(c);
    System.out.println(playerlist.size());
 }
}
```

CreationWindow

```
public class CreationWindow extends JDialog {

private JPanel contentPane;

private JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[5];
private JTextField name;
private ArrayList<JComboBox<String[]>> inputFields = new ArrayList<JComboBox<String[]>>();
private JButton create;

private MainWindow hf = new MainWindow();
private Character c;

public CreationWindow() {
    setTitle("Create a Character!");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 300, 250);
    setResizable(false);
    setModal(true);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    setCreationScreen();

    // Create Character
    create.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            /*
             *  2. As the class Character is abstract, the Object needs to be initialized with a subclass
             */

            switch (inputFields.get(0).getSelectedIndex()) {
            case 0:
                c = new Bowman();
                break;
            case 1:
                c = new Warrior();
                break;
            case 2:
                c = new Sorcerer();
                break;
            case 3:
                c = new Dwarf();
                break;
            }

            /*
             *  3. setting values of the Character Object
             */

            c.setCharacter(name.getText(), inputFields.get(1).getSelectedIndex() + 1,
                    inputFields.get(2).getSelectedIndex(), inputFields.get(3).getSelectedIndex());

            /*
             *  4. goes back into MainWindow
             */

            hf.createCharacter(c);
            dispose();
        }
    });
}

private void setCreationScreen() {
    // Erstellung Arrays für combobox-items
    String[] points = new String[29];
    String[] hours = new String[10];
    String[] classes = new String[4];

    // Initialisierung Arrays
    for (int x = 0; x < 29; x++) {
        if (x < 10) {
            hours[x] = String.valueOf(x);
        }
        points[x] = String.valueOf(x + 1);
    }
    classes[0] = "Bowman";
    classes[1] = "Warrior";
    classes[2] = "Sorcerer";
    classes[3] = "Dwarf";

    int a = -20;
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        labels[x] = new JLabel();
        if (x < 4) {
            if (x < 1) {
                inputFields.add(new JComboBox(classes));
            } else if (x < 2) {
                inputFields.add(new JComboBox(points));
            } else {
                inputFields.add(new JComboBox(hours));
            }
            if (x < 1) {
                inputFields.get(x).setBounds(25, a + 120, 110, 20);
                labels[x].setBounds(25, a + 105, 100, 15);
            } else {
                inputFields.get(x).setBounds(160, a + 100 + (x - 2) * 40, 80, 20);
                labels[x].setBounds(160, a + 85 + (x - 2) * 40, 90, 15);
            }
            contentPane.add(inputFields.get(x));
        } else {
            labels[x].setBounds(25, a + 45, 100, 15);
        }
        contentPane.add(labels[x]);
    }
    labels[0].setText("Character-Class");
    labels[1].setText("Willpoints");
    labels[2].setText("Strengthpoints");
    labels[3].setText("Hours");
    labels[4].setText("Name");

    name = new JTextField();
    name.setBounds(25, a + 60, 110, 20);
    contentPane.add(name);

    create = new JButton("Create");
    create.setBounds(160, 165, 100, 30);
    contentPane.add(create);
}
```

}

Character

```
public abstract class Character {

private String name;
private int willpoints;
private int strenghtpoints;
private int hours;
private boolean isKo = false;

// Constructor
public Character() {

}

public Character(String n, int wp, int sp, int h) {
    name = n;
    willpoints = wp;
    strenghtpoints = sp;
    hours = h;
}

public void setCharacter(String n, int wp, int sp, int h) {
    name = n;
    willpoints = wp;
    strenghtpoints = sp;
    hours = h;
}

// Getters and Setters

// Methods
```

}

Subclasses inherit from Character and don't have any differences as of yet.

Subclasses are: Bowman, Dwarf, Sorcerer, Warrior

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a problem here:

```
public class CreationWindow extends JDialog {

     // ....

    private MainWindow hf = new MainWindow();
```

You're creating a completely new unique MainWindow instance within CreationWindow, and any changes made to this object will not be reflected in the original MainWindow that displays the GUI.

The solution is to pass a valid reference to the original MainWindow instance into your new CreationWindow object. Use the CreationWindow constructor for this.

i.e.,

```
public class CreationWindow extends JDialog {

     // ....

    private MainWindow hf;  // do not instantiate

    public CreationWindow(MainWindow hf) {    
         this.hf = hf;
```

And call it like:

```
    cw = new CreationWindow(MainWindow.this);
```

---

Unrelated issue --  you really don't want to do this:

```
contentPane.setLayout(null);
```

Using null layouts and `setBounds(...)` may seem like a great way to easily create complex GUI's, but once you get beyond the newbie stage you'll find out that this way is wrong, that it only makes things much more difficult for you and for your users. Avoid this except for very certain exceptions (and this isn't one), and instead learn and use the layout managers.

Comment: I love you. The call to CreationWindow is inside an ActionListener, so (this) won't work. Can you help me out there as well? How do I tell the constructor that 'this' isn't the ActionListener but the class MainWindow?

Comment: @unnamed use the object-specific `this` here: `MainWindow.this`.

Comment: Didn't even see your edit for the Layout! Thanks for hinting that one out, could you recommend a link where this topic is explained easily to comprehend?

Comment: @unnamed: a bunch of resources to be found in the [tag:swing] tag, including this link: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info). Please check it out.